# Fragment content position in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, progress-bar

I was trying to fix this for a while and couldn't find the problem. I have a fragment in which I have ProgressBar that is centered. Here is the xml file content of fragment.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/details_form"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

I also have activity and I just add this fragment to the activity. Here is the xml of activity

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/details_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MyActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

The problem is when I navigate to this activity inside my application the progress is shown on the left side, it is not centered. I am not sure why is this happening, so I thought someone will see something I am missing. Thanks.

EDIT:

In onCreate event of my activity code (MyActivity.java) I have this code:

```
DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
            agreementDetailsFragment.setArguments(arguments);
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.details_container,
                            detailsFragment).commit();
```

and in my fragment .java file in onCreateView I have this code

```
View rootView = null;
        /*
         * Get root view
         */
        LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, wrapper, true);
        rootView = wrapper;
```

Comment: How exactly do you use that layout(the one with merge) in the fragment?

Comment: Have you tried just using a RelativeLayout and android:layout_centerHorizonal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"

Comment: RelativeLayout here LinearLayout wrapper = new LinearLayout(getActivity());?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is when I navigate to this activity inside my application
>   the progress is shown on the left side, it is not centered. I am not
>   sure why is this happening, so I thought someone will see something I
>   am missing. Thanks

The layout with the `merge` tag will have as a parent a `LinearLayout`. In a `LinearLayout` the `android:layout_gravity` will not work and you'll need a more permissive layout like a `RelativeLayout` or a `FrameLayout`(I'm assuming that the `ProgressBar` and the `details_form` `LinearLayout` will replace each other using the visibility property):

```
RelativeLayout wrapper = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_fragment, wrapper, true);
```

Comment: I tried this, now progress is in the top left corner (before this it was vertically centered but not horizontally).

Comment: I changed FrameLayout in fragment xml to RelativeLayout as well and instead android:layout_gravity I used android:gravity and it centered progress bar. Thanks guys.